# How to add/update gpg.conf configuration file to Heroku

Tags: heroku, gnupg, pgp

**Some Context:**
We are running a rails server and need to include gpg.conf with `ignore-mdc-error` in order to decrypt a PGP encrypted file from a client (note: we asked them to --force-mdc when encrypting but have not received that updated file yet so we need this workaround).

**Request:**
I am trying to add a root folder and file `.gnupg/gpg.conf` to our heroku server. I'm not sure how to add this kind of configuration, please let me know what method you think will work.